# How to Hide and Show a button with if statements c#

Tags: c#, if-statement, button

I am trying to make a button `visible = false` if a quantity in a text box is less than or equal to 0. The problem I am having is that you have to click the button in order to activate the function.

Here is my code so far

```
int quantity = int.Parse(textBox33.Text);

if (quantity <= 0)
    button13.Visible = false;

if (quantity > 0)
    button13.Visible = true;
```

do I have to disable the visibility of the text box beforehand?

Comment: If you don't want to have a postback, you should use javascript (JQuery).

Comment: you're talking about winforms application, WPF application, ASP.net web...?

Comment: Sorry, I was talking about c#

Comment: you invoke the if after you pushing the button?

Comment: Where is this code? In the button-click-handler? Put it in the `TextChanged` event handler of your textbox, because it should be executed when your user changes the textbox's content. And please tag your question appropriatly: is this about winforms, wpf or any other UI framework (c# supports many of them)?

Comment: You can shorten the code by button13.Visible = quantity > 0

Answer (score 1):

At first you should encapsulate the code to update the button in a specific method:

```
private void UpdateButton13()
{
    button13.Visible = quantity > 0; // no need for if/else
}
```

Then you can call this from every event after which the button should be updated. From your comments it seems you want to update that button

- at Form load and
- when the text in `textBox33` has been changed.

So for example:

```
public class YourForm : Form
{
    public YourForm()
    {
        InitializeComponents();

        // register event handlers:
        Load += YourForm_Load;
        textBox33.TextChanged += textBox33_TextChanged;
    }

    private void YourForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateButton13();
    }
    private void textBox33_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateButton13();
    }

    private void UpdateButton13()
    {
        button13.Visible = quantity > 0; // no need for if/else
    }
}
```

Of course you can also create and register the event handlers in the designer window, without having to write the code in the constructor yourself.

---

The code above may now seem a little redundant (same code in two methods and a one-line method). But I assume that you want to do further things on loading the form and on changing text, and maybe you want to call `UpdateButton13` from other parts of your code, too. So encapsulating here is good style (imho) to avoid problems for further development.

Answer (score 0):

go to textbox events and insert the code to textChanged event.

but for better than that you can do digit validation event

```
private void textBox33_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
        if (!System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(e.KeyChar.ToString(), "[1-9]"))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
}
```

in that case order can be only positive number

Comment: I do this but it still wont work when the form loads, they only really become invisible when the number in the textbox becomes -1

Comment: @DMcCracken of course, that event is only fired if the `TextBox`' `Text` is changed. If you want to execute code at form load, call that code from the `Form` 's `Load` event handler, too.

Comment: you passing value to that textbox on load ?

Comment: i understand that you have some sort of shop and you didn't want to get negative quantity so make it impasible to enter by digit validation on keyPress

Answer (score 0):

Simply go to the form editor and double click on the textbox. In the code presented to you after double clicking add your code or double click on the form itself if you want the code to be executed whenever the form is loaded.